# Can't use Ignite loadCache method with IgniteBiPredicate

Tags: postgresql, ignite

I'm using Apache Ignite as a cache backed by a postgres database too large to initialize all at once.  Instead, I want to load selective pieces into my cache on an as-needed basis.  I wanted to do this via loadCache (since readThroughEnabled mode only works for simple cache operations, which I can't guarantee we'll be using), which accepts an IgniteBiPredicate as an argument.  However, whenever I try to use an IgniteBiPredicate as filter, I get ClassCastExceptions that prevent me from loading the cache.

This is for a single node of Ignite local to my server.  I have tried taking my cache and calling "loadCache(biPredicate, null)" on it to attempt to load the specific data I want.  This is an example of my code with some domain specifics stripped out:

```
public void initFoo(int key){
  IgniteCache<Integer, Foo> myCache = getCache(Foo.class);
  if (myCache != null){
    myCache.loadCache(new IgniteBiPredicate<Integer, Foo>() {
      @Override
      public boolean apply(Integer integer, Foo foo){
        return integer == key;
      }
    }, null);
  }
}
```

I would expect this to result in my cache being loaded, at least the part that I care about for this particular entry.  Instead I see

```
"Failed to load cache:  Foo"
...(lots of nested exceptions eventually leading to)
...
"Caused by:  jvaa.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryObjectImpl cannot be cast to 
com.sms.Foo"
```

I am confident this is not a problem in my cache configuration (at least at the level of the Java object) as when I did a simple loadCache with no arguments, the entire cache loaded fine and was usable.  Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are getting BinaryObject's instead of your POJO objects.

You can just choose to [work with BinaryObject](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#section-binaryobject-and-cachestore)'s, or there should be a setting to reverse this behavior. Try cacheCfg.setStoreKeepBinary(false) when creating cache, for example.

**UPD:** I have checked it and it seems that storeKeepBinary isn't used. Anyway, you can do `Foo foo = binaryObject.deserialize();` if you like. I'm still not sure if this is configurable or if this closure just gets what is thrown to it.

Comment: Does that mean that instead of an IgniteCache<Integer, Foo> I should be using an IgniteCache<Integer, BinaryObject>?  That seems bizarre to me, I have a configuration for the cache that defines the value types, and have had no problem referring to Foo objects when doing ScanQuery operations.

Comment: Yep. If you will especially like working with BinaryObjects you can also employ them in ScanQueries by doing `withKeepBinary(true)`.

Comment: Why does it only retrieve objects as BinaryObjects and not as Foo, when in other places I'm able to directly cast them to Foo?  Is loadCache different than the queries somehow?